# SMACSS\BEM - how to correctly handle icon style?

Tags: css, sass, less, smacss

I have two nested modules:

```
<div class="header">
.....
<i class="topIcon"></i>
......
</div>
```

I have two separate files (I would like to keep it separate because they are reusable parts and can be used separately throughout the application) acting as modules in SMACSS terminology:
Header:

```
.header {
   /* header styles */
}
```

Icon:

```
.topIcon {
 /* icon styles */
}
```

Now I want to apply some styles to my `topIcon` when `header` has `:hover` state.
I can put `.header:hover .topIcon` inside my icon module file and apply style, however from my POV it breaks SMACSS rules.

Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: what does BEM have to do with any of this?

Comment: BEM is a closed to SMACSS. Some devs use BEM with SMACSS and vice versa. I believe that the same issue (you need an access to parent Block from child Block) may arise in BEM as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to do it by using [Sass' & selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Referencing_Parent_Selectors_____parent-selector):

```
.topIcon {
  /* icon styles */

  .header & {
    /* modified styles when it's in header */
  }
  .header:hover & {
    /* modified styles when it's in header thats hovered */
  }
}
```

The result would be

```
.topIcon {
  /* icon styles */
}
.header .topIcon {
  /* modified styles when it's in header */
}
.header:hover .topIcon {
  /* modified styles when it's in header thats hovered */
}
```

That way, I keep the icon-related styles in the icon file, but avoid "foreign" classes at a root level.

A weak point of that way might be, that you might also have another rule for .header:hover in the header file, which might be confusing for others, where to place what.

Comment: I'll stick with your approach for now. Thank you!